# How to allow protocol-41 (6in4) through the GCE firewall?

Tags: google-compute-engine, ipv6, tunnel

As a stop-gap until Google supports [native IPv6 on Google Compute Engine](https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/detail?id=8), I'd like to configure a [6in4 (IP protocol 41) tunnel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6in4).

I added a firewall rule to allow protocol 41 on my VM's network:

```
Name        Source tag / IP range  Allowed protocols / ports  Target tags
allow-6in4  216.66.xxx.xxx         41                         Apply to all targets
```

And configured the tunnel in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto 6in4
iface 6in4 inet6 v4tunnel
  address 2001:470:xxxx:xxxx::2
  netmask 64
  endpoint 216.66.xxx.xxx
  gateway 2001:470:xxxx:xxxx::1
  ttl 64
  up ip link set mtu 1280 dev $IFACE
```

And `ping6 2001:470:xxxx:xxxx::1` and verified that 6in4 traffic was outbound:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -pni eth0 host 216.66.xxx.xxx
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
22:52:03.732841 IP 10.240.xxx.xxx > 216.66.xxx.xxx: IP6 2001:470:xxxx:xxxx::2 > 2001:470:xxxx:xxxx::1: ICMP6, echo request, seq 1, length 64
22:52:04.740726 IP 10.240.xxx.xxx > 216.66.xxx.xxx: IP6 2001:470:xxxx:xxxx::2 > 2001:470:xxxx:xxxx::1: ICMP6, echo request, seq 2, length 64
22:52:05.748690 IP 10.240.xxx.xxx > 216.66.xxx.xxx: IP6 2001:470:xxxx:xxxx::2 > 2001:470:xxxx:xxxx::1: ICMP6, echo request, seq 3, length 64
```

I changed the endpoint temporarily to an address where I can run tcpdump, and confirmed that packets are not arriving at the destination.  I even tried NAT myself in case GCE wasn't doing this for 6in4 packets, but no luck (`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p ipv6 -j SNAT --to-source 130.211.xxx.xxx`).

Has anyone gotten a 6in4 tunnel to work on a GCE VM?  Is there some magic setting I missed somewhere?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TL;DR: You can't.**

Per [Networking and Firewalls](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking):

> Traffic that uses a protocol other than TCP, UDP, and ICMP is blocked, unless explicitly allowed through Protocol Forwarding.

Per [Protocol Forwarding](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/protocol-forwarding/):

> Google Compute Engine supports protocol forwarding for the following
>   protocols:
>
> AH: Specifies the IP Authentication Header protocol.
>
> ESP: Specifies the IP Encapsulating Security Payload protocol.
>
> SCTP: Specifies the Stream Control Transmission Protocol.
>
> TCP: Specifies the Transmission Control Protocol.
>
> UDP: Specifies the User Datagram Protocol.

Hence, a Protocol Forwarding rule needs to be for one of the following [IP protocol numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IP_protocol_numbers):

- 51 (AH)
- 50 (ESP)
- 132 (SCTP)
- 6 (TCP)
- 17 (UDP)

The [Protocol Forwarding](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/protocol-forwarding/) page makes it clear that other protocol numbers, such as [41 (6in4)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6in4) are not supported:

> Note: This is an exhaustive list of supported protocols. Only protocols that appear here are supported for protocol forwarding.

Comment: Looks like google cloud platform is still using stone-aged infrastructure.  No native ipv6 and not even allowing tunnels.